# Google Speech APi is not converting Full audio text

Tags: google-speech-api

HI we implemented google speech api , in our node js project .my client library is node js .we are converting first file into flex format then storing to google bucket .then url using for converting in to text . problem we are facing that ful audio file is not converting in to text . only half file is converting in to text . no errors is coming .

Comment: when using streaming there is a 60 sec (I think) limit so you have to partition your audio. I never tried like you're doing it.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked constraints related to voice duration? 
https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/basics